# Find values in data frame and return them in new column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

data frame is 12 columns
id, season, week, season_type, start_date, home_team, home_points, away_team, away_points, Line, home_cover, away_cover

```
        id season  week season_type start_date home_team        home_points away_team             away_points  Line home_cover away_cover
      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
1 400603840   2015     1 regular         42251. South Carolina            17 North Carolina                 13  -3.5 Y          N         
2 400763593   2015     1 regular         42251. UCF                       14 Florida International          15 -17   N          Y         
3 400763399   2015     1 regular         42251. Central Michigan          13 Oklahoma State                 24  20.5 Y          N         
4 400603839   2015     1 regular         42251  Vanderbilt                12 Western Kentucky               14 -17.5 N          Y         
5 400756883   2015     1 regular         42251. Utah                      24 Michigan                       17  -3   Y          N         
6 400763398   2015     1 regular         42251. Minnesota                 17 TCU                            23  16   Y          N
```

what want is to find what team each away_team and home_team played the week before
and cannot figure it out for life of me

Comment: According to this data, nobody played anything the week before. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on making a question self-contained and ***reproducible*** (key word), including data that is both minimal and representative of your problem.

Comment: Yes that’s just the head week goes 1-16 season goes 2015-2020, how much more of the day would be needed for this question?

Comment: Think about it: how many weeks do *you need* to see in a solution that would justify in your mind that the method worked robustly and consistently? One week is obviously not enough; two weeks? It might be luck that it happened to work. Three weeks is getting better. My answer below shows four weeks, which I think does a reasonable job of demonstrating the problem. You can test with my data (it's completely reproducible) if you'd like, then adapt (column names and such) to your own data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest `dplyr` for this, as I think it's easier to understand the flow.

First, though, your sample data does not include multiple weeks, so it is insufficient to demonstrate this. Here's a little sample data (don't worry about understanding this part, it's just to create fake data):

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
dat <- bind_rows(lapply(1:4, function(w) data.frame(season=2021, week=w, home_team=sample(LETTERS[1:4]), away_team=sample(LETTERS[5:8]))))
dat
#    season week home_team away_team
# 1    2021    1         A         F
# 2    2021    1         D         H
# 3    2021    1         C         G
# 4    2021    1         B         E
# 5    2021    2         D         H
# 6    2021    2         C         E
# 7    2021    2         B         G
# 8    2021    2         A         F
# 9    2021    3         D         G
# 10   2021    3         B         E
# 11   2021    3         C         H
# 12   2021    3         A         F
# 13   2021    4         D         E
# 14   2021    4         A         F
# 15   2021    4         C         G
# 16   2021    4         B         H
```

From here, we'll (1) shift the data a week, then (2) "join" twice. (For a good read on the concept of merge/join, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272.))

```r
shifted <- dat %>%
  transmute(week = week + 1, home_prevaway = home_team, away_prevaway = away_team)
left_join(dat, shifted, by = c("week", "home_team" = "home_prevaway")) %>%
  left_join(., shifted, by = c("week", "away_team" = "away_prevaway"))
#    season week home_team away_team away_prevaway home_prevaway
# 1    2021    1         A         F          <NA>          <NA>
# 2    2021    1         D         H          <NA>          <NA>
# 3    2021    1         C         G          <NA>          <NA>
# 4    2021    1         B         E          <NA>          <NA>
# 5    2021    2         D         H             H             D
# 6    2021    2         C         E             G             B
# 7    2021    2         B         G             E             C
# 8    2021    2         A         F             F             A
# 9    2021    3         D         G             H             B
# 10   2021    3         B         E             G             C
# 11   2021    3         C         H             E             D
# 12   2021    3         A         F             F             A
# 13   2021    4         D         E             G             B
# 14   2021    4         A         F             F             A
# 15   2021    4         C         G             H             D
# 16   2021    4         B         H             E             C
```

`home_prevaway` is the previous team the current home team played; similarly for `away_prevaway`.

For verification, in week 1 team "B" (home) played team "E" (away), and team "D" played team "H". In week 2, B's `home_prevaway` is "E", and D's `home_prevaway` is "H". (The fact that teams A and D played the same away two weeks in a row is an inconvenient coincidence given the random data.)